# problem with Google identity sign-in with redirect (server-side)

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, google-authentication, google-identity, google-identity-toolkit

I've been trying to update Google sign-in button on my website from old javascript method to new identity library, it works fine when I use callback function but the redirect option (for server-side verification) doesn't send credentials in POST request:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
    <div id="g_id_onload"
         data-client_id="my client id"
         data-ux_mode="redirect"
         data-login_uri="http://localhost:3001/api/google-auth">
    </div>
    <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In POST request it sends 'g_csrf_token' cookie, but doesn't contain 'credential' or 'g_csrf_token' in request body or parameters as mentioned in the document here

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#server-side

I believe I've set OAuth 2.0 Client ID and Consent Screen correctly. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The new sign in splits sign-in   (authentication)  and Oauth (authorization) completely.     Just sign in is only going to get you an id token.    You wont get a consent screen unless you use the authorization system.  see [this page](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration#authentication_and_authorization)

Comment: Thanks, I only need authentication to sign-in users with their google email and name. The problem is it doesn't give me an id token in POST

Comment: If I just use the html code above it's supposed to redirect user to sign in, then sends a POST request with JWT credential to login_uri according to Google document. but it doesn't contain any credential in the POST request.